# WCF timeouts in SOME solutions

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio, web-config, timeout

The problem is that when I create a new solution in VS2012 and add service reference of wcf, everything works fine. However, when I add the same service reference to one of my projects, the methods receive timeout exception. The problem might be that when I add the reference to my project, visual studio didn't create the codes until I uncheck the option "Reuse types in referenced assemblies". I checked configuration files but see no difference at all. I include a part of config file anyway:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint address="url"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
    contract="NewsBannersCampaignService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
</client>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DefaultBinding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="project.Services.Integration">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding" name="Integration" contract="project.Services.IIntegration" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

**Edit:** For anyone that may have this problem; the problem in my case was I forgot to delete my defaultProxy setting in config file. After deleting it everything worked fine. I just deleted

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
       <proxy proxyaddress="http://address" bypassonlocal="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```